# Creating Pandas DataFrame Column with Dashes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background -**
I am aware of the various ways to add columns to a pandas DataFrame, such as `assign()`, `insert()`, `concat()` etc.. However, I haven't been able to ascertain how I can add a column (similar to `inset()` in that I specify the position or index) and have that column populated with dashed values.

**Expected DataFrame structure -**
Per the following, I am looking to add `colC` and add `-` values that span the same length as the columns that do have data.

```
print(df)
    colA  colB colC
0   True     1    -
1  False     2    -
2  False     3    -
```

In the above example, as the DataFrame has 3x rows, `colC` populates with `-` values for all 3x rows.

Comment: `df['colC'] = '-'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as it gets.

```py
>>> df
    colA  colB
0   True     1
1  False     2
2  False     3

>>> df['colC'] = '-'
>>> df
    colA  colB colC
0   True     1    -
1  False     2    -
2  False     3    -
```